# User profile and active directory sync

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

I understand the concept of AD syncing with Sharepoint online to feed in details like name, job title etc.

My confused about what happens when we add/update property values in sharepoint. Does it sync back to AD. If so then how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no properties will sync back to AD if you update them in the UPSA in SPO.

Comment: Not clear Trevor. what happens to newly added properties in SPO User profile? are they local to sharepoint user management list only.?

Comment: New properties added to the UPS Properties list only exist in that SP Farm. If you want to enable Export to AD you can, but it is not automatic.

Comment: @SB23 SPO cannot write back attributes to either Azure AD nor on-prem Active Directory. SPO has an import-only sync for the attributes it supports. You would need to create a custom solution to import the attributes back to AD